# Spring Boot response has already been committed exception for request to mp4 resources

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot (v1.3.5) deployed on Tomcat8 server.

I've already tried use

```
@Component
public class ServletCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

@Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container
 {
    MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
    mappings.add("webm", "video/webm");
    mappings.add("mp4", "video/mp4");
    container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
 }
}
```

When I reload the page with any mp4 video I get the "response already committed exception" as below stack trace

> 2016-08-16 16:46:16.229 ERROR 12969 --- [o-8080-exec-268] o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/uploads/surveys/videos/16/20160721121310248+0000.mp4] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
>
> org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:393) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:426) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:339) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:418) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:406) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.write(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:540) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.copyRange(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:552) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.writePartialContent(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:501) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:271) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at net.caiena.survey.web.security.TokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(TokenAuthenticationFilter.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.4.RELEASE.jar:4.0.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:120) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:95) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:113) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.33]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
>       at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]

Comment: Dat stack trace doe...

Comment: `Cannot forward to error page` There's something else going on; you should post *the code responding to the request*.

Comment: hi @Greek got any solution